# How to do responsive 5columns (grids). [bootstrap]

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I wanted my home-page to be responsive. I have already 5columns which is equal each. I really don't have idea on how to do this.

**My index.html**

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4">
    <img src="img/user.png" alt="">
    <h2>Temp1</h2>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-half">
    <img src="img/user.png" alt="">
    <h2>Temp2</h2>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-half">
    <img src="img/user.png" alt="">
    <h2>Temp3</h2>
</div>  
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-half">
    <img src="img/user.png" alt="">
    <h2>Temp4</h2>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-half">
    <img src="img/user.png" alt="">
    <h2>Temp5</h2>
</div>
```

**My style.css**

```
.col-half{
    margin-left:4.166666667%
}
```

**From col-lg this:**[image]

**(Expectation) I wanted to be like this when col-md:** [image]

Is there any way of doing this? I did my very best, but I end up nothing. I'm a beginner of Bootstrap, Sirs, please help.

Comment: is this for Bootstrap 3 or 4? you have both tags

Comment: @mlegg I'm using Bootstrap 4 Sir. Sorry for mistakes. Thanks anyway Sir, I already got the answer from D. Smania.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check next example I made with [Bootsrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/). The main approach for the layout you described is using the [offseting of columns](https://getbootstrap.com/) for the screen types **LG** and **MD**.

- The class `text-center` is used for horizontally center the images and text on every column.
- The class `img-fluid` is for make responsive images: [Bootstrap Responsive Images](https://getbootstrap.com/)

**Note** that you have to play with the snippet example on fullscreen and resize the browser...

```css
img {
    max-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

  <div class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-2 col-md-4 text-center">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    <h2>Temp1</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 text-center">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    <h2>Temp2</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 text-center">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    <h2>Temp3</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-2 offset-lg-0 offset-md-2 col-md-4 text-center">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    <h2>Temp4</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 text-center">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    <h2>Temp5</h2>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row flex-md-wrap flex-nowrap justify-content-between justify-content-md-center flex-column flex-md-row">

  <div class="text-center mr-md-3">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200/000000/fff.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    <h2>Temp1</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="text-center mr-md-3">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200/000000/fff.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    <h2>Temp2</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="text-center mr-lg-3">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200/000000/fff.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    <h2>Temp3</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="text-center mr-md-3">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200/000000/fff.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    <h2>Temp4</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="text-center">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200/000000/fff.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    <h2>Temp5</h2>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```